# How to handle View Expired Exception in JMeter

Tags: xml, jmeter, partial-response

I am testing Login page in my ADF Application using JMeter 3.2. In my Test Plan, I have used HTTP Header Manager and Cookie Manager. I got all HTTP records by recording. I have correlated each request from its previous response using regular expression extractor. Correlated parameters are `jsessionid`, `adf.ctrl-state`, `afrLoop`, `afrRedirect`, `javax.faces.ViewState`. But for a particular request, I am getting "session expired" error even if all the parameters are extracted and passed correctly (verified from its previous response). Getting response as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response>
   <error redirect="true">
      <error-name>ViewExpiredException</error-name>
      <error-message>Because of inactivity, your session has timed out and is no longer active.  Click OK to reload the page.</error-message>
   </error>
</partial-response>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check whether WindowId needs to be correlated in the script.It is also one of the parameters which needs to be correlated in Oracle ADF framework

However ViewExpiredException will be thrown when the associated view state isn't available in the session anymore.So check once whether all the view state values captured and passed on to the corresponding requests correctly.
Try to use any web debugging tool like Fiddler or mozilla fire bug to inspect all the requests.

Comment: Surya, Happy about your response. I have tried to correlate Window id too. there is no change. also have verified each parameter value by using firebug. Still I could nt overcome this issue.